# Error executing Insert, Update, Delete statement using apache calcite

Tags: java, sql, apache-calcite

The execution of Insert, Update and Delete statements using Calcite fails, and I cannot confirm the cause of the error.

[Results]
[Input query]

```sql
DELETE FROM  customer
```

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

[Parsed query]

```sql
DELETE FROM `CUSTOMER`
```

[Logical plan]

```
LogicalTableModify(table=[[CUSTOMER]], operation=[DELETE], flattened=[false]), id = 5
  LogicalProject(c_custkey=[$0], c_name=[$1], c_address=[$2], c_nationkey=[$3], c_phone=[$4], c_acctbal=[$5], c_mktsegment=[$6], c_comment=[$7]), id = 4
    LogicalTableScan(table=[[CUSTOMER]]), id = 1
```

[Physical plan]

```
EnumerableTableModify(table=[[CUSTOMER]], operation=[DELETE], flattened=[false]), id = 20
  EnumerableCalc(expr#0..7=[{inputs}], proj#0..7=[{exprs}]), id = 19
    EnumerableTableScan(table=[[CUSTOMER]]), id = 13
```

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Baz.bind(Unknown Source)
    at com.github.zabetak.calcite.tutorial.LuceneQueryProcessor.execute(LuceneQueryProcessor.java:243)
    at com.github.zabetak.calcite.tutorial.LuceneQueryProcessor.main(LuceneQueryProcessor.java:115)
```

Expect to execute Insert, Delete, Update statements correctly

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.